# Hg - switch draft phase commits to a branch

Tags: mercurial

I've committed several changesets and am now thinking that it might have been better on a new branch. I haven't pushed changes yet so they're still in the draft phase. Is there some mercurial way (that doesn't involve re-cloning) that I can just change these over to a branch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Update to the parent of first improperly (to the wrong branch) committed changeset
- Create needed branch (`hg branch ...` + `hg commit ...`)
- Rebase changesets to the new parent (starting changeset of branch)